# Report Studio: Scheduling and prompting with one report

Tags: report, cognos

I have a report that filters an sql query with a date. I want to have this report in two versions. One that goes on in a schedule (it uses the actual month) and another one that prompts for the date to be filtered.

One is supposed to run every month by itself and the other one will be used in a few manual runs.

Can I do this without having more than one report?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a prompt called pPeriodType with two possible values: 'Select Date Range' or 'Current Month'

Then in your report filter you do something like this:

```
  (
  ([YourDate] BETWEEN 
  ?pStartDate? AND ?pEndDate?) 
  AND ?pPeriodType? = 'Select Date Range'
  )
OR
  (
  [YourDate] BETWEEN 
  <expression evaluating to start of month based on current date>
  AND 
  <expression evaluating to end of month based on current date>
  AND ?pPeriodType? = 'Current Month'
  )
```

Now when you pick 'Current Month', it will show current month regardless of the dates you pick. When you pick 'Select Date Range' it will filter based on the selected dates. You just need to work out the expression for start and end dates depending on the current date. What database are you running this on?

Comment: Are you saying you want me to come up with a DB2 expression to find start and end month?  I googled it and found an expression here: http://leonardom.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/db2-first-day-of-month-and-last-day-of-month/

Comment: No, I already did that part of the first and last from another post. What I wanted is to have one report to use with or without prompt. Thanks for your time